# jquery how to access selected data

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a JSon string convert with jquery tmpl to produce a list of city around latitude and longitude coordinates.

The result like this :

```
<input id="50b62c795c92ae12bcbcbf04" class="bob" type="radio" title="Québec" longitudeconfirm="-71.3508909" latitudeconfirm="46.8608225" citycodeconfirm="2" countrycodeconfirm="CA" value="50b62c795c92ae12bcbcbf04" name="placeid" checked="checked">

<input id="50b62c795c92ae177e6a7c0d" class="bob" type="radio" title="Québec" longitudeconfirm="-71.3709" latitudeconfirm="46.8725" citycodeconfirm="2" countrycodeconfirm="CA" value="50b62c795c92ae177e6a7c0d" name="placeid" checked="">
```

... and other the user can just select one in the list.  In this example user select the first one

I need in jQuery access to value of longitudeconfirm, latitudeconfirm, citycodeconfirm, countrycodeconfirm and value (or id is the same value)

I need to access the value when user click on submit button to save his choice

Thank you for your help

Comment: Additionnal info : i need to access the value when user click on submit button to save his choice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to get attribute just use

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('body').on('change','.bob',function(){
        alert($(this).attr('longitudeconfirm'));
        // use it the same way to get any attr you want
    });
});
```

while you tagged a jquery so this is a jquery solution so please be sure to include jquery

after your Additionnal info *access the value when user click on submit*

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('body').on('submit','form',function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            alert($('.bob:checked').attr('value'));
            //for value you can also use 
            //$('.bob:checked').val();
        });
    });
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/nocp233g/1/)